# react native and expo: problem sending log messages symbolicatedStack

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, console.log

Recently I updated react (0.62.2) and expo (37.0.12). Nearly everything works fine. Except upon every App reload and shortly after an error occured, an error screen pops up that displays

```js
console.error: There was a problem sending log messages to your development environment TypeError: 
symbolicatedStack.map is not a function. (In 'symbolicatedStack.map(removeProjectRoot)', 
'symbolicatedStack.map' is undefined
```

covering the previously occured error.

since there is no `symbolicatedStack` written by myself, I suspect its an internal error, but I can't figure out what it is. Upon pressing "Dismiss" everything works fine again. (Till the next reload/error)

Expo / React version are compatible according to their offical websites.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is dues to version missmatch try running  expo upgrade command. It should resolve your issue.